# Test whether a node contains escaped XML using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping, libxml2, libxslt

I'm attempting to clean-up a batch of XML I've been provided. There are three situations I need to account for:

1. some elements have plain text within them, eg. `<item>some text</item>`, which need to be wrapped in another tag, eg. `<item><p>some text</p></item>`
2. some elements have escaped XML within them, eg. `<item>&lt;p>some text&lt;/p></item>`, which needs to be output without escaping: `<item><p>some text</p></item>`
3. some elements have escaped XML which needs to be wrapped, eg. `<item>some &lt;em>text&lt;/em></item>` needs to become `<item><p>some <em>text</em></p></item>`

`<item>` is used as a container in both instances.

I can satisfy condition one relatively easily, and I can satisfy condition 2 with `disable-output-escaping`, but I can't satisfy condition 3 with this approach.

I think I can satisfy 2 (& possibly 3) if I can test whether the text within `<item>` is escaped, but a test using `contains(., '&amp;lt;')` doesn't match. So...

How can I test whether text within a node is escaped XML?

Comment: `contains(., '&lt;')` works?

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly do you use? Have you checked whether an extension function is available or can be easily implemented that parses the content of the `item` elements into a tree fragment which could then be processed with normal templates as needed?

Comment: @MaxToro No, since that's essentially searching for `<` escaped for use within the test attribute of XSL.

Comment: @MartinHonnen updated the tags with relevant information, but essentially I'm using `libxml2` and `libxslt`.

Answer (score 0):

1. and 3. both need wrapping and disable-output-escaping in 1. won't hurt so I think you can treat them together with the same template.

I don't see a clear check whether an element content contains an escaped element markup with pure XSLT 1.0 means, so I simply tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[not(*) and not(starts-with(., '&lt;') and substring(., string-length(.)) = '&gt;')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[not(*)
                          and starts-with(., '&lt;') and substring(., string-length(.)) = '&gt;']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<root>
<item>some text</item>
<item>&lt;p>some text&lt;/p></item>
<item>some &lt;em>text&lt;/em></item>
</root>
```

into

```
<html><body>
<item><p>some text</p></item>
<item><p>some text</p></item>
<item><p>some <em>text</em></p></item>
</body></html>
```

Obviously it would transform `<item>&lt;...></item>` as well into `<item><...></item>`. You could try to implement some more string checks but without a complete parser for the escaped XML fragment it is always possible to construct input samples where the string checks fail.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've come to the same conclusion that I'll need to parse the escaped content to ensure it is well-formed, so I'm going to add a callback to the language I'm using (Python+lxml) to handle this.